# Python 3 version for Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame, python-3.10

I have an M2 Macbook Air, and am looking to install `python 3`, along side with `pygame`. At the moment, pygames site notes that python 3.11 is not supported. If I can't install the latest `python 3.11.x`, should I install `python 3.10.10`, dated `Feb 8, 2023`, or should I look at some `python 3.x` version dated even further back?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you want to use the latest supported python version?

Comment: Well the M2 chip is still relatively new, and I just wanted to make sure that the latest python 3.10.10 version really is supported, since I wasn't able to find anyone who has worked with Pygame via python 3.10.10

Comment: Even more reason to get the latest supported version since there's more chance it will work correctly with M2.

Comment: But what are the chances it would work with pygame?

Comment: Do you want us to estimate the chances? It's 50% - either it works or not. But you should just test it rather than asking.

Comment: I installed python3.11.x on an intel mac alongside pygame. I thought pygame wasn't compatible with python3.11.x right now?